# In objective-c what is the purpose of returning nothing in an if state when comparing two values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, conditional-statements, uitableview

The code below works with a UIViewTable to help move rows to different positions in a table.

Anyway there is an if statement present and I'm trying to figure out it's purpose. It's not like there is any code inside the if statement so what's its use.. Is it only there to throw an error if `from` isn't equal to `to`?

I don't understand it's purpose and the book doesn't explain either. I'm guessing `return;` returns nothing. So is basically void? and if `to` is equal to `from` nothing happens.

**Code:**

```
- (void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from toIndex:(int)to
{
    if (from == to) {
        return;
    }

    // Get pointer to object being moved so we can re-insert it
    BNRItem *p = [allItems objectAtIndex:from];

    // Remove pointer from array
    [allItems removeObjectAtIndex:from];

    // Insert p in array at new location
    [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:to];
}
```

**To move a row**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] moveItemAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row] toIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
}
```

Thanks for your time
Kind regards

Comment: It's not that "nothing happens". `return` returns from the function, so if the two values compare equal, then the rest of the function is not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` is usually used to return a value from a function or method (hence the name). In a method that returns void (nothing) it can be used to exit the method at that point.

In your example if `from` is equal to `to` there is no reason to do anything, because you want to move a row to the same index that it is already at. So you just check for this case and return right at the beginning (and don't execute the following three lines).

The code below would have the exact same result, but you have an additional layer of indention and arguably it's not very elegant.

```
- (void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from toIndex:(int)to
{
    if (from == to) {
        // do nothing
    } else {

        // Get pointer to object being moved so we can re-insert it
        BNRItem *p = [allItems objectAtIndex:from];

        // Remove pointer from array
        [allItems removeObjectAtIndex:from];

        // Insert p in array at new location
        [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:to];
    }
}
```

Or just reverse the if statement and only execute the code if `from != to`:

```
- (void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from toIndex:(int)to
{
    if (from != to) {

        // Get pointer to object being moved so we can re-insert it
        BNRItem *p = [allItems objectAtIndex:from];

        // Remove pointer from array
        [allItems removeObjectAtIndex:from];

        // Insert p in array at new location
        [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:to];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok totally makes sense now. I do this a lot and not quite sure how I could miss this. I think the return by itself is what threw me off as this is the first time I've seen this. Your second example looks much nicer to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

When you get inside the method "moveItemAtIndex" you can get out of it and continue your code in 2 ways.
1. The method runs through all the lines of code inside it
2. You hit a line of code that says "return;"

So actually,
If (from != to), the other lines of code will run and the method will exit out after completing it

The lines that wont run if (from == to) are

```
// Get pointer to object being moved so we can re-insert it
    BNRItem *p = [allItems objectAtIndex:from];

    // Remove pointer from array
    [allItems removeObjectAtIndex:from];

    // Insert p in array at new location
    [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:to];
```

Answer (score 1):

> So is basically void? and if to is equal to from nothing happens.

Exactly right. It exits the method without doing anything else because that case (same position) is already the way the array is sorted.

It is a quick way to end processing for a method. There is no more work to do.

Answer (score 1):

All lines after `return;` won't be executed.

```
- (void)moveItemAtIndex:(int)from toIndex:(int)to

    if (from == to) {
        return;
        //All lines further down, won't be executed, it is a simple way to exit a method.
    }

    // Get pointer to object being moved so we can re-insert it
    BNRItem *p = [allItems objectAtIndex:from];

    // Remove pointer from array
    [allItems removeObjectAtIndex:from];

    // Insert p in array at new location
    [allItems insertObject:p atIndex:to];

}
```